# What is the best way to load a lot of data from DataFlow to external postgres database?

Tags: python, postgresql, bigdata, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm running a pipeline with Python where I scrape a lot of data and want to load in an external database (Digital Ocean Postgres), I have some options but none of them looks nice in performance (or I can't evaluate the performance properly):

- Using `from beam_nuggets.io import relational_db` which has some downsides about performance, since it loads line by line;
- Uploading grouped data into `pubsub` where I could run some Cloud Function to upload to the external db, however even groping this could be a big data for a Cloud Function to run and there are some limits in terms of how many messages and the size of messages I can publish;
- Uploading to `bucket` where I can run the Cloud Function, but this way I would face the same issue about a lot of data for a function to process and splitting would be a lot of function calls;

For me it would be nice (I think) if I could upload a bunch of data in one insert, something like `COPY TO` but I can't run this on DataFlow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After you submit your Dataflow pipeline, Dataflow services start several workers (i.e., VM) to execute your pipeline. Each worker will be assigned certain key range for parallel execution and shuffle data to another worker if necessary (i.e., GroupByKey). Therefore, in general your pipeline has better performance if you have large key number and smaller key value size.

In your case of "a big data for a function to run", if your data is associated to many keys where the same function is run for these keys, that is probably fine. However, if you mean a big data for one key running in a function (i.e., DoFn), then it can hit performance issue as it may slow down key parallelism, and you are likely to hit some system limit (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/quotas). For example, there is a size limit for a single element.

Just some ideas for the latter case: you may consider splitting your (single big) data to many pieces and assign to different keys (e.g, with common prefix). At database query layer, you can query them according to, say, prefix. Or if your database support key value appending, you can read your (single big) data in batch within a key and append the result to the database.

I think a good starting point is to check google provided template (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates), where you can find examples of reading data from GCS and insert processed data to BigQuery. You may do something similar.

Comment: Sorry, I used function in a generic way, I meant Cloud Function, inside the pipeline I use DoFn and I would use it for insertion, but it would make a lot of insertions (even in parallel), in my mind it would be better to insert all or by chunks. And about BigQuery, it's easier since it has some codes to performance bulk load, but I want to load to an external database.